# PdfBox: the end of the stream doesn't point to the correct offset

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am getting the following warning when trying to upload a document using PdfBox: The end of the stream doesn't point to the correct offset, using workaround to read the stream, stream start position: 162, length: 1125, expected end position: 1287.

It is being produced in the validateStreamLength() method of class COSParser. Additionally, I see a significant spike in threads. So, is there any way to turn off the workaround to read the stream and throw an exception instead?.

Comment: It is possible to turn off leniency, but I looked into the source code, it won't fail for this type of (minor) error. The thread spike is likely to have a different cause.

Comment: *"when trying to upload a document using PdfBox"* - how do you *upload* a document using pdfbox? That being asked, you appear to have a lot of issues loading damaged pdfs. Are you sure the input files already are damaged? Or is it possible that your code retrieving and forwarding it to pdfbox does the damage? In the latter case I'd propose checking that code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.